# How do I retrieve updating html content in realtime? (Java)

Tags: java, web, httpconnection

I've already tried using `HttpConnection` and `HttpClient` to get the content of an index.html from a website. The problem is, that it only gives me the original html and then doesn't continue/wait to read. The site I want to read is constantly changing its html code, since it is updating after a while if you are on it.

How can I open a "session" in Java, so it retrieves the content after it updates, or at least waits for the website to load a little longer, since the image elements of the website are generated through php afterwards.

Comment: The images in a web page are usually loaded via separate requests. You will need to parse the image urls from the HTML in the response and request them separately. Dynamic changes to web pages might happen in two ways. Most likely, Javascript running in the web browser will make further requests to the server and use the data to changes the page. More rarely the whole page might refresh itself periodically. Perhaps you could use a real browser and something like Selenium?

Comment: Hey, the problem is, that the images do not have the same file name as always.

Could you give me an example on Selenium?

Thank you for answering!

Comment: Here's an introductory Selenium article: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-write-your-first-script-in-selenium-webdriv

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look into it!
I'll still let this question open tho, since I'd prefer a Java Vanilla solution